# Can $(X, τ)$ be a nontrivial topological space such that $(τ,X)$ is also a topological space and a metric space under the same metric?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Can $(X, τ)$ be a nontrivial topological space such that $(τ,X)$ is also a topological space and a metric space under the same metric?

I'm looking at the Collatz graph as a surjection from a subset of $\omega^\omega$ onto itself and it appears to have this property.

FWIW my thinking about the answer to this is that it would require $τ$ to be a family of sets drawn from the powerset of $X$ and vice versa, and therefore requires $τ=X$.  Would this be correct?

EDIT:
This only seems possible with [non-well-founded forms of set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-well-founded_set_theory) as it requires breaking [Russel's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).  Is this correct, and e.g. can $X=\{X\}$ have this topology?

Comment: You're on the right track doubting this question in the last paragraph.  $X$ and $\tau$ are of different types, so asking if $(\tau,X)$ is a topology is beyond wrong.

Comment: @MatthewDaly If the proposition is correct that there are limited circumstances in which a set can be a family of sets over a family of sets drawn over itself, it'd be great to understand the circumstances in which it can happen - trivial topology, the empty set only, etc.

Comment: Not even in limited circumstances. To give the extreme example, the only topology on the empty set is $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$, so $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$ isn't even a topology.

Comment: @MatthewDaly I want to put $X=\{\{\},X\}$, but of course that is not a set.  But putting that aside, would that work?

Comment: By definition of topology you have $X\in\tau$. If $(\tau,X)$ were a topological space too you would have $\tau\in X$. This kind of $\in$-loops are ruled out by the axiom of foundation

Comment: Thanks @AlessandroCodenotti nicely put.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already noted, this cannot work in any well-founded set theory; in particular, it won't work in ZF (with or without choice).

However in other set theories, it is indeed possible. For example, when replacing the axiom of foundation with [Aczel's anti-foundation axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aczel%27s_anti-foundation_axiom), the set you've brought up in the comments,
$$X = \{\emptyset,X\}$$
is indeed an example (actually, the simplest one). It gives the trivial topology over itself.

With anti-foundation, $X$ is a set because it corresponds to a two-node graph where one node has a loop and an arrow to the other node. The node with the loop is the root.

Comment: Thank-you.  This makes me think "general relativity" of set theory!  I was expecting A (a two-node graph where one node has a loop and an arrow **from** the other node) but you have described B: https://imgur.com/a/te3FhSU Is that correct?

Comment: @samerivertwice: Yes. The arrow always goes from the set to the element. The root stands for the set described by the graph. So $X$ has two elements, $X$ itself (giving the loop on the root node) and the empty set (going from the root to the other node). The empty set has no elements, and thus doesn't have any outgoing arrows.

Answer (score 7):

Reposting my comment as an answer.

By definition of topology you have $X\in\tau$. If $(\tau,X)$ were a topological space too you would have $\tau\in X$ as well, but it's impossible to have such loops of membership as a consequence of the axiom of foundation.